# How to generate queries and skip parts of queries in Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using Python to query Elasticsearch with a custom query. Let's look at a very simple example that will search for a given term in the field 'name' and another one in the 'surname' field of the document:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import json
# read query from external JSON
with open('query.json') as data_file:    
    read_query= json.load(data_file)

# search with elastic search and show hits
es = Elasticsearch()
# set query through body parameter
res = es.search(index="test", doc_type="articles", body=read_query)
print("%d documents found" % res['hits']['total'])
for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
    print("%s) %s" % (doc['_id'], doc['_source']['content']))
```

'query.json'

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "Star",
              "boost": 2 
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": { 
            "surname": "Fox"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I am expecting the input of search words from the user, the first word that is typed in is used for the field 'name' and the second one for 'surname'. Let's imagine I will replace the {$name} and {$surname} with the two words that have been typed in by the user using python:

```
'query.json'

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "{$name}",
              "boost": 2 
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": { 
            "surname": "{$surname}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now the problem arises when the user doesn't input the surname but only the name, so I end up with the following query:

```
'query.json'

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "Star",
              "boost": 2 
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": { 
            "surname": ""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The field "surname" is now empty and elasticsearch will look for hits where "surname" is an empty string, which is not what I want. I want to ignore the surname field if the input term is empty. Is there any mechanism in elasticsearch  to set a part of query to be ignored if the given term is empty?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": {
              "query": "Star",
              "boost": 2 
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": { 
            "surname": "",
            "ignore_if_empty" <--- this would be really cool
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe there is any other way of generating query strings? I can't seem to find anything about query generation in Elasticsearch. How do you guys do it? Any input is welcome!

Comment: You should use the [Python DSL](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/) in order to construct your query dynamically depending on the input you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python DSL seems to be the proper way of doing it https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/